# Open multiple instances of a HTA from the same file

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, hta

I've got a HTA that queries an MSSQL Server's sys.dm_exec_requests table to locate rogue long-running queries that may be causing speed issues in our EMS, and while it works great, I'd also like to use it for other systems.

To this end I changed it so it would accept a command line parameter for the server name.  This works great, but I've found that I can't have more than one window open at a time.  If I try, it uses the existing window.

Is there a way to do this without having multiple copies of the file and giving each one a unique ID (which is going to be hell for maintainability) or am I just going to eat some concrete in regards to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your `.HTA` header for:

```
<HTA:APPLICATION  
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
```

Change `SINGLEINSTANCE` to `no`

Comment: I stand before you an idiot - it was staring me in the face the whole time.  Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Heh -- That sounds like me at work.  Happens to all of us.  Since you're new here to SO, let me remind you to accept an answer when you get a chance.  (I think you've got delay right now.)

Comment: Yeah, I was just waiting for the delay to lapse.  I tried and it kept saying I had to wait.